# Implementing stdout.write / stderr.write in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, stdout, stderr

I have some Node.js code, and would like to get it running the browser. In many places in my Node.js code, I have made calls to `process.stdout.write` and `process.stderr.write`.

In the browser, we have console.log / console.error

I do not need high-performance here. If I implement these methods in the browser like so:

```
process.stdout.write = function(v){
   console.log(v);
};

process.stdout.error = function(v){
   console.error(v);
};
```

that's obviously not going to really get us what we want.
Is there a way to hook into console.log / console.error in the browser to print to stdout/stderr without printing a newline char?

Comment: Are you saying you *do* want the text to appear in the browser's console, but you want to be able to control when it adds newlines? Your last sentence is still talking about printing to stdout/stderr.

Comment: yeah that's right - I want typical console.log behavior for the browser, but I want the lower level control that comes with process.stdout.write. I want to control when newlines are added, etc. I don't know if there's anything lower level than console.log for the browser.

Comment: You can apply CSS styling to individual logged items, and create nested (indented) groups that can be collapsed, but I'm not aware of any built-in methods for preventing line breaks. I guess you could write your own log function that caches the text to be logged, and doesn't actually call `console.log()` until it receives text containing a `\n`, and/or until a timeout that you specify.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var stdout = '';
process.stdout.write = function(s) {
  stdout += s;
  for (var i; -1 !== (i = stdout.indexOf('\n')); stdout = stdout.slice(i + 1))
    console.log(stdout.slice(0, i));
};
```

Ditto for stderr.

But you'll need a way to flush the last slice.